# Records should be deleted from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, named-query

I have 2 tables Taxcon and Tax .If I delete a record in tax then the releated records in the taxcon should be deleted

i want a namedquery for that.

I tried this Query

```
delete t,c from TaxCon t JOIN t.tax c WHERE  c.code=:code
```

->Here my intention is to delete the record in the tax table  with the help of "code" field and the related record in the Taxcon should be deleted
But I am getting a error called
The query contains a malformed ending

Comment: Why don't you configure them as `FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE  CASCADE`? Then they'll be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need a joining condition so that only the related rows of the two tables are deleted.

```
DELETE t, c
FROM TaxCon AS t
JOIN Tax AS c ON t.code = c.code
WHERE c.code = :code
```

But you can make this happen automatically by declaring a foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE TaxCon ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES Tax (code) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then you only have to delete the row in `Tax` and the related `TaxCon` rows will be deleted.